# Change on every line to catch slash and separate

Tags: perl, sed, awk, tr

I have txt file with a lot of lines the most of them repeat, want to change on every line which contains "find" make separation on the last "/" and to add after it " -name ".

Txt file:

```
find /etc/cron.*
find /etc/inet.d/*.conf
find /etc/rc*
grep root /etc/passwd
```

Expected view:

```
find /etc/ -name cron.*
find /etc/inet.d/ -name *.conf
find /etc/ -name rc*
grep root /etc/passwd
```

Comment: you say change lines which contain "find", but your example shows the grep line changing too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Modify every line which contains `find` only:

```
$ awk '/^find /{$NF=" -name "$NF}1' FS='/' OFS='/' file
find /etc/ -name cron.*
find /etc/inet.d/ -name *.conf
find /etc/ -name rc*
grep root /etc/passwd
```

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{$NF=" -name "$NF}1' file
```

```
$ cat file
find /etc/cron.*
find /etc/inet.d/*.conf
find /etc/rc*
grep root /etc/passwd

$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}{$NF=" -name "$NF}1' file
find /etc/ -name cron.*
find /etc/inet.d/ -name *.conf
find /etc/ -name rc*
grep root /etc/ -name passwd
```

Comment: Wow, brilliant, I was thinking on looping through all fields, etc but this is way better.

Comment: @fedorqui Since OP mentioned `last /`, I thought it would be better just to modify the last variable. `:)`

Comment: @jaypal singh tricky part here is to catch only find, see on grep is add " -name " also.

Comment: @KalinBorisov Actually your expected output shown above made me remove the `/find/` from the answer. Do `awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="/"}/find/{$NF=" -name "$NF}1' file` to modify only lines with `find`.

Comment: @Kent Which logo? That's my real name! `;)`

Comment: @jaypalsingh the photo. tux.

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -wpe's!^(find.*/)!$1 -name !' file
```

Add -i before -wpe to actually change the file.

On more modern perl versions:

```
perl -wpe's!^(find.*/)\K! -name !' file
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use warnings;
use strict;

open (FILE, "$ARGV[0]"); #pass file containing commands as first argument
my @file_contents = <FILE>;
close FILE;

#my @file_contents = (
#   'find /etc/cron.*',
#   'find /etc/inet.d/*.conf',
#   'find /etc/rc*',
#   'grep root /etc/passwd',
#);

#Build command line
foreach my $line (@file_contents){
    chomp $line;
    $line =~ s/(.*?) (\/.*\/)(.*)/$1 $2 -name $3/ if $line =~ /find/;
    print "$line\n";
}
```